# ListView only displays 3 of 4 records from database matching criteria set

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm an A Level Student currently working through my A Level Computer Science Controlled Assessment.  I am working in Android Studio, using Java, XML and SQLite, none of which I have used before.  I am building a Scout Manager application.

I'm currently working on displaying event details, specifically the names and sections of each Scout who has been invited to an event, and this is to be displayed in a ListView.  The only issue is, while 4 Scouts have been invited to this event in the database, only 3 are being displayed - or, one too few Scouts are being displayed.

It should be noted that there are separate tables for events, invites and scouts.  The invite table matches together the id of the event being attended, and the id of the scout who is attending it - therefore, I find all invites to a certain event, and then the individual scouts attending the event, before displaying the details of the scout.

Here is the code used to get the invites for a given event from the database, from my databaseHandler class:

```
public Cursor getEventInvites(int sessionid) {
    String[] columns={COLUMN_INID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID, COLUMN_SEID, COLUMN_SCID};
    String selection=COLUMN_SEID + " =? ";
    String[] selectionArgs={String.valueOf(sessionid)};
    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_INVITES, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Here is the code used to display details in a ListBox:

```
ListView scoutslist = findViewById(R.id.listScouts);
scoutdetailslist=new ArrayList<String>();
scoutadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, scoutdetailslist);
//ArrayList<int>
Cursor invites;
invites=DatabaseHandler.getEventInvites(sessionid);
invites.moveToFirst();
try {
    while (invites.moveToNext()) {
        int ScoutID = invites.getInt(invites.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_SCID));
        Cursor scout = DatabaseHandler.getScout(ScoutID);
        String forename = scout.getString(scout.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_FNAME));
        String surname = scout.getString(scout.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_LNAME));
        String section = scout.getString(scout.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_SECTION));
        String ScoutBasicDetails = forename + " " + surname + ", " + section;
        scoutdetailslist.add(ScoutBasicDetails);
    }
} finally {
    invites.close();
}
scoutslist.setAdapter(scoutadapter);
```

And here is the code used to get a Scout's details from the database.

```
public Cursor getScout(int scoutid) {
    String[]columns={COLUMN_SCID, COLUMN_FNAME, COLUMN_LNAME, COLUMN_DOB, COLUMN_SECTION, COLUMN_SEX, COLUMN_ADD1, COLUMN_ADD2, COLUMN_CITY, COLUMN_POST, COLUMN_RELIGION, COLUMN_ENAME, COLUMN_EHOME, COLUMN_EMOB, COLUMN_EEMAIL, COLUMN_MED, COLUMN_ALL, COLUMN_TET, COLUMN_SWIM, COLUMN_SCHOOL, COLUMN_PHOTO, COLUMN_MOVE};
    String selection = COLUMN_SCID + " =? ";
    String[] selectionArgs={String.valueOf(scoutid)};
    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_SCOUTS, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    if (cursor!=null&&cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    } else {
        cursor=null;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated - also, I'm new to this, and pretty tired, so if I've left out important details or been unclear please don't hesitate to leave a comment and ask me to amend the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving to the first item, then immediately moving to the next item (thus skipping the first item):

```
invites.moveToFirst();
try {
    while (invites.moveToNext()) {
```

Consider a do while loop that only executes if the `moveToFirst()` call succeeds.